# Async Wait Issue with Service when called out from the Controller in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am currently trying to do a get request in my NodeJS API, get some data and return the modified value.

From what I read in other similar questions is that you cannot just return the modified object but you need to use a **callback** function or a **promise** in order to return it. I have a standard MVC pattern where I use a `controller`, `service`.

Here is my service:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
exports.RequestUserPermissions = async function(role, next) {
  try {
    await rp('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8').then(response => {
      const permissionsResponse = JSON.parse(response);
      const filteredPermissions = permissionsResponse.find(function(x) {
        return Object.keys(x).indexOf(role) > -1;
      });
      console.log(filteredPermissions); // I GET UNDEFINED HERE.
      return filteredPermissions;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Here is my controller:

```
const UserPermissionsService = require('../services/userPermissions.service');


exports.getUserPermissions = async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const role = req.headers.role; // console.log(req.headers.role);
    const loggedInUserPermissions = await UserPermissionsService.RequestUserPermissions(role);
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: loggedInUserPermissions, message: 'User permissions retrieved.' });
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error(error, 'error inside the get.user.permissions function');
  }
};
```

So my issue is that I'm trying to return the value of `filteredPermissions` to my controller but I keep getting undefined. Which I guess it's a `async` - `await` issue. Meaning that the function ends before I make my calculations.

I originally had my service as:

```
await request.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8', (error, response, body) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    const permissionsResponse = JSON.parse(body);
    const filteredPermissions = permissionsResponse.find(function(x) {
      return Object.keys(x).indexOf(role) > -1;
    });
    return permissionsResponse;
  } else {
    console.log('Got an error:', error);
  }
});
```

but I changed it to use the `request-promise` module, so that I can return my `response`. What am I doing wrong ? How can I pass my calculations properly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
await rp('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8')
```

to this:

```
return rp('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8')
```

You need to be returning something useful from your `exports.RequestUserPermissions` function.  As it stands now, there's no return value from that function which means the promise it returns will just have an `undefined` resolved value which is apparently what you are experiencing.

Then, I'd suggest using a `.catch()` for the error condition.  And, you need to allow the caller to see the error (probably as a rejected promise) so it can know when there's an error.

I would suggest this:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
exports.RequestUserPermissions = function(role, next) {
    return rp('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8').then(response => {
      const permissionsResponse = JSON.parse(response);
      const filteredPermissions = permissionsResponse.find(function(x) {
        return Object.keys(x).indexOf(role) > -1;
      });
      console.log(filteredPermissions); // I GET UNDEFINED HERE.
      return filteredPermissions;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      next(error);
      throw error;
    });
};
```

---

The spec for exactly what you want is a bit confused.  To be able to test things with the URL you gave me, I created a simple stand-alone node program here.  This looks for one matching `role` and returns that. If no matching role is found, it resolves to `null`.  You could also make that reject, depending upon how the caller wants no matching role to work.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

function getRole(role) {
    return rp({uri: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8", json: true}).then(data => {
        // need to find the matching role
        // apparently role can be a string or an array of strings
        for (let item of data) {
            if (item[role]) {
                return item[role];
            }
        }
        return null;
    });    
}

getRole("admin").then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When, I run this, I get this output:

```
{ static:
   [ 'posts:list',
     'posts:create',
     'posts:edit',
     'posts:delete',
     'users:get',
     'users:getSelf',
     'home-page:visit',
     'dashboard-page:visit' ] 
}
```

Hopefully, can you take this an modify to fit your other needs.

Note: I'm using the `json:true` option with `rp()` so it will parse the JSON response for me automatically.

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard - Did you look at `permissionsResponse`?  Is that what you expect?  It seems like either that isn't what you expect or your processing of it is flawed.  I don't know what it's supposed to be or what you're trying to do when processing it and have no ability to look at it or run your code so all I can do  on that issue is ask you questions.  If you show what `permissionsResponse` is and what result you're trying to get out of processing it, then maybe we could help with the processing of it.

Comment: If you access [this url](https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8) you'll see a set of permissions. I am just trying to get those permission, filter them based on the role and return only the permissions which apply to the role. 

I think I actually have an issue with the way my response is parsed. If I change my code from `const filteredPermissions = permissionsResponse.find(function(x){..}` to `const filteredPermissions = response.find(function(x){..}`

I get the error: response.find is not a function. I hope this comment will be more useful.

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard - OK, I can look at that.  What is a value for `role` that you would pass into this?  And, what's an example of the output you want?

Comment: Well I am currently passing "admin" but that will be something passed through the header. So it doesn't really matter. Regardless if it's admin, user or visitor, I'll need to fetch the corresponding permissions.

The tricky bit for me is that it could even be an array of 2 roles, for an example ["user", "admin"]. Now, any ideas why it's giving me back an `undefined` status? Also thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard -  So, if "admin" is passed, do you just want the `admin` object returned such as: `{"static": ["posts:list", "posts:create", "posts:edit", "posts:delete", "users:get", "users:getSelf", "home-page:visit", "dashboard-page:visit"]}` to be returned?

Comment: Yes. That'll be a start. I can do it in a JS bin example but I think the JSON gets parsed differently when fetched from an URL.

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard - And, if role is an array of strings, do you want the result to be an array of objects?  This question is frustrating because you're not being specific about input, arguments and desired output.  It's taking a lot of questions here to figure out what the actual specific is.

Comment: I apologize, I really do.  The role can be an array of strings and the result should be an array of objects yes.

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard - OK, before you added the part about an array of input and an array of output, I made an example (added to the end of my  answer) that works for a single role and a single return value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using async/await with `request-promise` then you don't need to call `.then()`, you can just assign your `rp` call directly to a variable. For example this:

```javascript
await rp('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8').then(response => {
      const permissionsResponse = JSON.parse(response);
      const filteredPermissions = permissionsResponse.find(function(x) {
        return Object.keys(x).indexOf(role) > -1;
      });
      console.log(filteredPermissions); // I GET UNDEFINED HERE.
      return filteredPermissions;
    });
```

Would become this:

```javascript
const response = await rp('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8');
const permissionsResponse = JSON.parse(response);
const filteredPermissions = permissionsResponse.find(function(x) {
  return Object.keys(x).indexOf(role) > -1;
});
console.log(filteredPermissions); // I GET UNDEFINED HERE.
return filteredPermissions;
```

Comment: I had almost this exact code typed up, you just beat me to it. Only difference was i had `const permissionsResponse = await rp('https://api.myjson.com/bins/7jau8').then(res => JSON.parse(res);`

Comment: Guess I also added a `catch` rather than except block

Comment: I just keep getting `undefined`. I doubt that it could be from the `filteredPermissions ` calculation..

Comment: What does `permissionsResponse` output to the console? If it's not `undefined` then it likely is your `.find` function.

LostJon's suggestion, depending on your preferences, makes the code a bit neater.

Comment: `[
  { visitor: { static: [Array] } },
  { users: { static: [Array] } },
  { admin: { static: [Array] } }
]
` this is the data I get then I `console.log(permissionsResponse);` If open the provided url, you'll see my data.

Comment: try returning a `Promise.resolve(filteredPermissions)` since you await it in the calling function.

Comment: Your find function seems okay. What about logging `role` out within the `find` block?

Comment: @Sarreph `role` logs out to `admin` but that is something I pass through the header. So what I'm trying to do is query the array by the returned role.